# How can either a pdf or a jpeg be viewed when master page only allows one path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms, master-pages

I created a Code First Entity Framework ASP.NET Web form app using C#, LINQ, and Master Pages in Visual Studio, so the tables were automatically created from the seed data that I entered manually, which is a list of work from my Graphic and Web Design portfolio. There are three categories: Page Layout, Illustration, and Web Design. When one of these three categories is clicked, another page shows a list of thumbnails, which are all jpg files. When one of the thumbnails is clicked, it should open another view to show a larger version of the portfolio piece. However, a problem is that some of the larger images are pdfs, and some are jpgs. Both the thumbnails and the larger images have the same name, except that some of the larger images have the pdf extension. Thumbnails and larger images are in different directories. The larger image that has the same name as the thumbnail is in the ImagePath. Previously, there was a problem with the pdfs not showing, so I added a PdfPath, but now the larger jpgs are not showing. Would it work to have a function in the code behind of the WorkDetails Master Page that said something like, "If there is a PdfPath, then, do this...else if there is an ImgPath, do this"?

**WorkDatabaseInitializer Class:**

```
public class WorkDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<WorkContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(WorkContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            GetWorks().ForEach(w => context.Works.Add(w));
        }

        private static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var categories = new List<Category> {
                new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = 1,
                    CategoryName = "Page Layout"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = 2,
                    CategoryName = "Web Development"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = 3,
                    CategoryName = "Illustration"
                },
        };
            return categories;
        }
        private static List<Work> GetWorks()
        {
            var works = new List<Work> {
                new Work
                {
                    WorkID = 1,
                    WorkName = "Menu",
                    Description = "Restaurant menu composed with Adobe InDesign", 
                    **ImagePath="",
                    PdfPath="GardenMenu.pdf"**,
                    CategoryID = 1
               },
               new Work
                {
                    WorkID = 2,
                    WorkName = "Dell Advertisement",
                    Description = "Dell Computer ad", 
                    **ImagePath="Dell.jpg",
                    PdfPath="",**
                    CategoryID = 1
               },

            };
            return works;
        }
    }
}
```

**Work Details Master Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WorkDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="Grafica.WorkDetails" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:FormView ID="workDetail" runat="server" ItemType="Grafica.Models.Work" SelectMethod ="GetWork" RenderOuterTable="false"> <ItemTemplate> <div> <h1><%#:Item.WorkName %></h1> </div> <br /> 
        <table> 
            <tr> 
        <td> 
            <a href="Catalog/Images/<%#:Item.PdfPath %>">
                <img src="/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ImagePath %>" style="border: solid;" alt="<%#:Item.WorkName %>" /> 
            </a>


</td> 
        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align:left;"> 
                    <b>Description:</b><br /><%#:Item.Description %> <br /> <span><b>Project Number:</b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.WorkID %></span> <br /> 

                </td> 

            </tr> 

        </table> 

                                                                                                                                  </ItemTemplate> </asp:FormView>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You either need that kind of logic or put the PDFs and the larger images in the same directory.

Comment: The pdfs and larger images have been in the same directory.

Comment: Oh, I see, The pdfpath and imagepath also contain the filename, presumably generated in some way? You're going to have to know which kind of file you're linking to.    

I believe servers can be set up to try different extensions (Apache at least) but this tends not to be used too often as it can lead to things breaking unexpectedly if server configurations aren't meticulously maintained.